# Visualizacion de una tabla en asp.net mvc html

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc

Buenas, tengo un una vista index generada automaticamente por el controlador en C#, necesito mostrar unas fotos en una tabla y cada 4 columnas se genere una fila automaticamente, pero no lo consigo hacer, solo me muestra las fotos de corrido creando columnas y ya, nose como poner un limite de 4 columnas y n filas cada vez que lo vaya requiriendo segun la cantidad de fotos en la Base de datos
Alguien que me ayude

```
            @model IEnumerable<Domain.User>

            @{
                ViewBag.Title = "Index";
            }

            <h2>Users</h2>

            <p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            </p>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="border-spacing:5px;">

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.PhotoInterior1))
                        {
                            <img src="@Url.Content(item.PhotoInterior1)" alt="Image" style="width:200px;height:300px" />
                        }
                </tr>
            }
            </table>
```

Comment: tu tabla no tiene fila. falta <tr> y </tr>

Comment: igual le agrego los <tr> y ya me los muestra por fila cada foto sin columnas, lo que necesito es poner un limite de 4 columnas y n filas, que se creen automaticamente cada vez que lo requiera segun las fotos que tenga en la base de datos

Comment: Si estás iniciando en ASP.net MVC, esto te será de ayuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY es un workshop maratónico realizado con la comunidad :D Bienvenido a SOes, saludos :D

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que necesitas algo como:

```
@model IEnumerable<Domain.User>

@{
                ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Users</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</p>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="border-spacing:5px;">
    <tr>
        @{ var itemCount = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                if(itemCount > 4)
                {
                    Html.Raw("<tr>");
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.PhotoInterior1))
                {
                        <td style="width:154.8px; height:252px">
                            <img src="@Url.Content(item.PhotoInterior1)" alt="Image" style="width:200px;height:300px" />
                        </td>
                }
                if (itemCount > 4)
                {
                    Html.Raw("</tr>");
                    itemCount = 0;
                } else {
                    itemCount++;
                }
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Asi como lo tienes no me dio pero me diste una idea y me funciono y lo hice algo parecido gracias